# Check if given function is Lebesgue Integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

> Is $f:\mathbb{R^{2}}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ with 
>   $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}+y^{4}} $$
>   Lebesgue integrable?

I already got the hint to use Fubini-Tonelli and divide the integral of $x$ into two parts, $x^{2}\le 1+y^{4}$ and $x^{2} > 1+y^{4}$. But I didn't really work for me.

Comment: For $a > 0$, what is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^2+x^2}\,dx$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Tonelli's theorem applies for measurable functions $\geq 0$, and under these mere conditions it holds that the multiple integral equals any intended repeated integral. Note that $f$ is continuous, so it is Borel measurable, and hence it is measurable. Note that $f \geq 0$, so Tonelli's theorem is applicable. Now fix any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and find $g(y) := \int_{0}^{+\infty} f(\cdot, y)$ and then find $I := \int_{0}^{+\infty} g(y)d y$. Note that $4I = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}f$, so whether $I <+\infty$ or not answers the question.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it and wil write it down now. $4I = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}f$ is because of S

Comment: I mean *symmetry?

Comment: @PeterGarder, Yeah, symmetry, which happens to be the nature of $f$ here :).

Answer (score 3):

Well,
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+y^4)+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^4}}\tag{1}$$
hence Fubini's theorem applies and
$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{1+x^2+y^4} = 2\pi\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^4}} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\tag{2}$$
by Euler's Beta function.

Comment: Is there another way to show that $(2)$ is $<\infty$? As I didn't use the Beta function so far.

Comment: @PeterGarder: the Beta function is only needed to compute the actual value of the double integral, the crucial part is that any continuous, bounded function $g(x)$ that behaves like $\frac{1}{x^2}$ as $|x|\to +\infty$ is Lebesgue-integrable. Both $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+y^4)+x^2}$ and $g(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^4}}$ meet such constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: show 
$$ \iint_{R^2}\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^4}dxdy=4\iint_{(R^+)^2}\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^4}dxdy<\infty$$